# Agave alternative

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a lightweight color scheme designer in Ubuntu, in the spirit of (the now abandoned project) [Agave](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/agave).

Any suggestions? I am at Ubuntu 20.10, with Gnome.

[image: Screenshot from now the now defunct home page of Agave (Wayback Machine)]
*Screenshot from now the now defunct [home page of Agave (Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160327025128/http://home.gna.org/colorscheme/)*

Comment: What is your current Ubuntu version?

Comment: @N0rbert I'm at 20.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was [last available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/agave) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

But it is still installable even on latest Ubuntu 20.10 with commands below:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/agave
cd ~/Downloads/agave
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/agave/agave_0.4.7-2.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gconfmm2.6/libgconfmm-2.6-1v5_2.28.3-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgnome/libgnome2-0_2.32.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgnome/libgnome-2-0_2.32.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libb/libbonobo/libbonobo2-0_2.32.1-3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.23-0ubuntu11.2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libb/libbonobo/libbonobo2-common_2.32.1-3_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/orbit2/liborbit-2-0_2.14.19-1build1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-vfs/libgnomevfs2-0_2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgnome/libgnome-2-0_2.32.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgnome/libgnome2-common_2.32.1-5ubuntu1_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgnome/libgnome2-bin_2.32.1-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-vfs/libgnomevfs2-common_2.24.4-6.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

And then it will launch by `agave` and work normally. Also you may have to look on MATE Color Selection tool:

> [image: agave and MCS]